# HTML page not executing external JavaScript file

Tags: html, leaflet

expected result:

My understanding of the below scripts is that I should be able to uncomment the `//src="PAWSmap.js";` line in the scripts portion of the HTML page, refer to the JavaScript file that should define the map I desire.

This would mean the JavaScript file would deal with the map and future data while the HTML would simply refer to that file to display it.

result:

The map box however does not show up in the web browser when I follow the above logic.

It DOES show up when I run the HTML as is below, where the map set up and var creating is held within the HTML script.

This despite having followed two tutorials that would suggest that I should be able to achieve the "expected" method, having followed them closely.

```js
const apiKey = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWF4ZHVzbyIsImEiOiJja3p3Mzh3cHQ4M2VuMm5waGE3c3NpcGRoIn0.RCKfV5n8aOn2AUbXiS2qqA';

var map = L.map('map',{
    center: [43.64701, -79.39425],
    zoom: 15
    });

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        #map{
            height: 800px;
            width: 800px;
            margin: 5rem auto;
        }
    </style>

    <h2>
        Critiacally Listed Species in BC
    </h2>


</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

<script>

    //src="PAWSmap.js";

    var map = L.map('map',{
    center: [54.259070, -124.943178],
    zoom: 6
    });

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Question:

Why is the reference to the JavaScript map file not working whereas the creation of the mapbox within HTML does work?

Comment: You're not asking a question, and your code is not enough to reproduce any problem. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: hopefully my edits make it more clear

Comment: The line `src="PAWSmap.js"` assigns the string "PAWSMap.js" to the variable `src`. That is all. Nothing else, no files loded. I'm not sure where you got that exptectation from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to load an external JavaScript file from your HTML page is:

```html
<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>
```

Note that the `src` *attribute* and its value are *within* the `<script>` tag angle brackets, not as a *child* (i.e. not in between the opening and closing tags).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script for further details about the syntax and possible attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how I missed that.